# Partition by multiple columns having duplicate values in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

As an example, I have two columns in a table

```
**Fruit Color**
Mango Yellow
Mango Yellow
Apple Red
Apple Red
```

Expected Output

```
**Rank Fruit Color**
1    Mango Yellow
1    Mango Yellow
2    Apple Red
2    Apple Red
```

Tried Row_number() but it doesn't seem to yield the expected output. Tried Rank() and Dense_Rank() as well but didn't get the expected outcome

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fruit,Color order by Fruit) , Fruit,Color
from #temp
ORDER BY FRUIT

rwno    Fruit   Color
1   Apple   Red
2   Apple   Red
1   Mango   Yellow
2   Mango   Yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `dense_rank()` and no `partition by`:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Fruit, Color), Fruit, Color
from #temp
ORDER BY FRUIT
```